# Qt6 migration - UIC generated code fails to compile (connect slots) - updated

Tags: qt, qt6, uic

I'm trying to port my project from Qt5 to Qt6.
My problem is that UIC generated code looks like this:

```
QObject::connect(SelectHome, &QToolButton::clicked, toQPSQLSettingUI, qOverload<>(&QWidget::selectHome));
```

MSVC2019 compilations fails with:

```
ui_toqpsqlsettingui.h(74,101): error C2039: 'selectHome': is not a member of 'QWidget'
C:\Qt\6.0.4\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets\qcompleter.h(57): message : see declaration of 'QWidget'
C:\Users\I542264\source\repos\tora\src\ui_toqpsqlsettingui.h(74,1): error C2065: 'selectHome': undeclared identifier
```

See the target is method is `QWidget::selectHome`, so IMHO MSVC is right: QWidget does not have method `selectHome`. But target should be sub-class method `toQPSQLSettingUI::selectHome`

[image: Designer screenshot]

Complete source is [here](https://github.com/tora-tool/tora/blob/16429d82f781c40636528ec0d85f645ea859d83b/src/connection/toqpsqlsettingui.ui). Initially created for Qt2, migrated to Qt3=>Qt4=>Q5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>toQPSQLSettingUI</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="toQPSQLSettingUI">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>600</width>
    <height>517</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>600</width>
    <height>0</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form1</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout">
   <property name="margin">
    <number>11</number>
   </property>
   <property name="spacing">
    <number>6</number>
   </property>
   <item row="0" column="1" colspan="2">
    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="PGSQL_HOME"/>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="TextLabel6_2_2_2">
     <property name="toolTip">
      <string>The default dateformat to use when querying the database.</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>PgSQL home</string>
     </property>
     <property name="wordWrap">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="buddy">
      <cstring>PGSQL_HOME</cstring>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="0">
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>20</width>
       <height>40</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="3">
    <widget class="QToolButton" name="SelectHome">
     <property name="text">
      <string>...</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <tabstops>
  <tabstop>PGSQL_HOME</tabstop>
 </tabstops>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>SelectHome</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>toQPSQLSettingUI</receiver>
   <slot>selectHome()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>606</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>314</x>
     <y>258</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
 <slots>
  <signal>signal1()</signal>
 </slots>
</ui>
```

Comment: This line: `<widget class="QWidget" name="toQPSQLSettingUI">` tells that the class of `toQPSQLSettingUI` is `QWidget`. But in order to use the `selectHome` slot (which does exists in a subclass, I assume), you need to "promote" the widget to the subclass (which is done by right-clicking the widget in Qt Creator design mode and then choosing the promote action).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have too many .ui files to edit them with Qt Designer or even manually.

Comment: I have not. I just had to stop using QDesigner to connect slots. And I rewrote mine code to use connect on source code level. Luckily then new connect mechanism based on templates, simply won't compile if you make a typo.

Comment: See here https://github.com/tora-tool/tora/commits/qt6 , https://github.com/tora-tool/tora/commit/c8e215e33f3ce6ccc7b2cc71c67fcc5914bf5940

Answer (score 1):

**steps to fix**

1. within qtcreator open the concerned UI file in designer
2. press `<F4>` to toggle **edit signals / slots**
3. double click the blue `clicked()` label to open the connection configurator
4. click **Edit...** to customize the signals / slots
5. add the missing slot `selectHome()`
6. **OK**
7. **OK**
8. Save the UI file
9. Compile

another way would be to edit the UI xml
add within
`<ui><slots>`

```
  <slot>selectHome()</slot>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Qt6 UIC is using the new `connect()` syntax instead of the old `SIGNAL()`/`SLOT()` syntax, and it's scoping slots to the base class instead of the derived class. (In the OP's case, scoping `selectHome()` to `QWidget` instead of `toQPSQLSettingUI`.)

Adding the below to the `.pro` or `.pri` file and rerunning qmake causes UIC to use the old `connect()` syntax:

```
QMAKE_UIC_FLAGS += --connections string
```