# Using derived QLabel with buddy in .ui file generates incorrect code

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, uic

Have plenty of .ui files with derived classes, but now I decided to derive `QLabel` in some places. These use the "buddy" feature.

Relevant part of the .ui file:

```
<widget class="ItemLabel" name="icon">
</widget>
<widget class="ItemLabel" name="item">
  <property name="buddy">
    <cstring>icon</cstring>
  </property>
</widget>
```

...and this definition at the bottom of the .ui file:

```
<customwidgets>
 <customwidget>
  <class>Itemlabel</class>
  <extends>QLabel</extends>
  <header>ui/widget/ItemLabel.h</header>
 </customwidget>
</customwidgets>
```

Generates this code:

```
icon = new ItemLabel(item_parent);
icon->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("icon"));

item = new ItemLabel(item_parent);
item->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("item"));
item->setBuddy("icon");
```

Where the last line is obviously incorrect as the argument should be a `QWidget *`. It should be (and also is, for non-derived `QLabel`s) like this:

```
item->setBuddy(icon);
```

It seems that the "magic" understanding of what a buddy is, is lost when deriving. That is, that it should realize that the `icon` is to be treated as a variable name and not a string.

Is there a way to inform it about this magic again?
(it does not matter if the buddy widget is derived or not)

Using, Qt 5.15.2. Haven't tried other versions, but I did find this [Qt6 migration - UIC generated code fails to compile (connect slots) - updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643618/qt6-migration-uic-generated-code-fails-to-compile-connect-slots-updated) unanswered question, which touches on this topic.

edit: Here's the complete ItemLabel.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <QLabel>

class QMouseEvent;

class ItemLabel : public QLabel
{
public:
    explicit ItemLabel(QWidget *parent=nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f=Qt::WindowFlags());
    explicit ItemLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent=nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f=Qt::WindowFlags());

private:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) override;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done almost exactly this in Qt 5.15.3 on Linux, and it seems to work just fine.

More specifically, I have a class `InfoText` that derives from `QLabel` and a class `InfoButton` that derives from `QPushButton`.  In my .ui file, I have:

```
        <widget class="InfoButton" name="infoButton_name"></widget>
...
        <widget class="InfoText" name="infoText_name">
         <property name="buddy">
          <cstring>infoButton_name</cstring>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>...</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
...
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>InfoButton</class>
   <extends>QPushButton</extends>
   <header>widgets/InfoButton.h</header>
  </customwidget>
  <customwidget>
   <class>InfoText</class>
   <extends>QLabel</extends>
   <header>widgets/InfoText.h</header>
  </customwidget>
...
 </customwidgets>
```

In the generated ui_xxx.h file, I get:

```
...
#if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        infoText_name->setBuddy(infoButton_name);
...
#endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
...
```

So it looks like what you're doing in the .ui file should work.  Is there anything in the .h or the .cpp file for your `ItemLabel` class that might be confusing the Qt MOC?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. I worked around the issue by resolving the buddy myself by setting a custom property. I've also since this was asked migrated to Qt6, but the issue is actually still there (if I go back to the standard buddy property). There's not much to be confused about that I can see... I've added the complete ItemLabel.h to the question.